# Docker&Java: building doesn't reflect the new files

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I've just started to use Docker and I don't know why the Wildfly's docker container doesn't have the latest files even though it copies the war. I have a JS file which I've changed things in it, but whenever I access `127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/myjs.js` I still get the older one even though I've `sudo mvn clean install` the app and then build the image.

I've a docker-compose file which looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
   app:
      build: 
         context: .
         dockerfile: ./docker/docker-app/Dockerfile
      ports:
         - "8080:8080"
      links:
         - "db:task_book_db"
      depends_on:
         - "db"
   db:
      image: mysql:5.7.22
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=sample_db
          - MYSQL_USER=sample_usr
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sample_pw
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
   start_dependencies: 
      image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
      depends_on:
         - "db"
```

I do `sudo docker-compose run --rm start_dependencies && sudo docker-compose up --build app` and whenever I've changed something, I just stop the app container then I do `sudo docker-compose up --build app` again. I've read about volumes but I'm not sure how to use them yet.

Comment: Use `sudo docker-compose up --build -d` to re-create container with no cache

Comment: It might be occurring due to cache. Try accessing once you clear the cache.

Comment: Could you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: @YugSingh yep it was the browser's cache. I've cleared it and now it works fine. Thanks. Answer the question so I can declare answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

> This issue might be because of browser cache. Try accessing the `127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/myjs.js`
>   after clearing the cache.